# WebAPI: Upload picture & get byte array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, mime-types

I want the user to be able to upload a file via my application. I don't have DB access, all my data calls get completed via a web-service that another person is writing. I needed to secure the web service, so I've consumed it & exposed it via WebAPI, & added OAuth security.

Now to my problem.

I've written the following.

```
        public Task<FileResult> Post()
        {
             if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
             {     
                  var task = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ContinueWith(
                         o =>
                        {
                            var result = this.Client.UploadPicture(this.UserId, o.Result);

                            if (result.ResultCode == 0)
                            {
                                return new FileResult()
                                {
                                    Message = "Success",
                                    FileId = result.ServerId
                                };
                            }

                       throw new HttpResponseException(...);
                  });

              return task;
             }
        ...
       }
```

I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to WebAPI & multithreading (I'm not sure why this needs to be handled async? I'm sure there is a reason, but for now I'd just like a working example and get to the why later..).

My code is loosely based on some R&D & samples I've found on the net, but i haven't come across a scenario like I'm needing to complete... Yet it doesn't seem like I'm doing something out of the ordinary...

**Upload a file to the server, and pass the image byte[] object to either sql or another service?**

In this line

```
    var result = this.Client.UploadPicture(this.UserId, o.Result);
```

I'm uploading a byte[] array of something....

Then later (the retrieval method works, I've managed to retrieve & view a test image)

When retrieving the byte array of the "image" i uploaded i get an array of idk what.. EG, i get a valid result of something, but it ain't no picture. Which leads me to believe that the uploaded data is bogus :|

O_o
How to get the image byte[]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mime Multipart](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) is more than just your array of bytes.  It also has metadata and boundary stuff.  You need to treat it as MultiPartContent and then extract the image byte array out of that. 
Filip has a blog post on the subject [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/).